# Cannot add foreign key constraint When Upgrade 1.9.2.3 from 1.4.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, upgrade, magento-1.4, upgrade-script

Try to ***upgrade a magento system from 1.4.0.1 to lastest 1.9.2.3***.

Getting error to *Mage_Customer module's at upgrade installer* file `mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php`

**Throwing error:**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:199:"Error in file: "app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/
customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint";i:1;s:970:"
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
```

- **How to resolve this**.
- **What is reason for error**;

Comment: Foreign key in that file relates `eav_attribute` table with `customer/form_attribute`. Were you able to figure this one out ?

Comment: Please add complete stack trace so we can help you. Especially, what is the query?

Comment: Fabian, this project was gone.i does not have it rresource..... sorry for thay

Comment: As an idea you can try with default 1.4.0